# Serverless-offline: route not found statusCode": 404

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

Serverless offline not getting route.
I am using
"serverless-offline": "^3.25.4",
"serverless": "^1.0.0" version

```
    "statusCode": 404,
    "error": "Serverless-offline: route not found.",
    "currentRoute": "post - /dev/v1/authn",
    "existingRoutes": [
        "post - /v1/authn"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you requested `POST /dev/v1/authn`, however the only routes in your app are `POST /v1/authn`.

Remove `/dev/` from your request and it should work.